# Conversion of arrays list into readable table with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, statsmodels

I'm running some ARIMA fitting in Python 3 and I want to save the results of the Ljung-Box test into a text file (or into an object to be written later to a file) but the output of the test is far from readable as is.

An example of the function is:

```
from statsmodels.stats import diagnostic as dst
ljung = dst.acorr_ljungbox(db['FTSEMIB'], lags=10, boxpierce=True)
```

and the output looks like this:

`(array([a, b, c]),array([1, 2, 3]),array([d, e, f]),array([4, 5, 6]))`

What I would like to obtain in the final output file is something like:

```
a 1
b 2
c 3

d 4
e 5
f 6
```

Comment: What's `a`,'b` etc?  To Python code those look like variable names.  You'll get an error if they aren't defined.  But your desired output suggests they are strings, `'a'`?

Comment: Did an answer below help? Feel free to accept an answer (green tick on left), or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way using `numpy`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = (np.array(['a', 'b', 'c']),
     np.array([1, 2, 3]),
     np.array(['d', 'e', 'f']),
     np.array([4, 5, 6]))

A = np.array(x)

df = pd.DataFrame({0: A[::2].ravel(), 1: A[1::2].ravel()},
                  index=range(int(A.shape[1]*A.shape[0]/2)))

print(df)

   0  1
0  a  1
1  b  2
2  c  3
3  d  4
4  e  5
5  f  6
```